# How to keep django_q cluster running in linux server?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, scheduled-tasks, django-q

I am using django_q for some scheduling and automations in my django project.

I successfully configured all the needed stuff but to get django_q running I have to type in the server command line 'python manage.py qcluster' and after i close the shell session id doesn't work anymore.

In the django_q official documentation it says that there is no need for a supervisor, but this is not running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi you might find something to your taste here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you can use.

1. You could install the screen program to create a terminal session which stays around after logout. See also: https://superuser.com/questions/451057/keep-processes-alive-after-ssh-logout
2. You could use systemd to automatically start your qcluster. This has the advantage that it will start qcluster again if your server is rebooted. You'll want to write a service unit file with `Type=simple`. Here's a [list of resources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files).

   Here's an example unit file. (You may need to adapt this somewhat.)

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=qcluster daemon

   [Service]
   User=<django user>
   Group=<django group>
   WorkingDirectory=<your working dir>
   Environment=PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/   bin/
   ExecStart=python manage.py qcluster
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the qcluster up and running you need to create a service. A service is a process that can run in background.

## The structure to define service is as below

```
[Unit]
Description=Some description

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/python /path/to/project/manage.py qcluster
Restart=always
```

The above must be placed in a file which should be named as `<filename>.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` directory

To start the service you should use the command `sudo systemctl start <filename>.service`

To start the service during the start up use the command `sudo systemctl enable <filename>.service`

## Other way to run the qcluster at background not recommended

By using screen, a screen in linux is multiple virtual terminals that will be running at background even after getting detached.

To create a screen enter
`screen`

Now run the qcluster

Then detach from the screen using
ctrl + a and ctrl + d

To see all screens created, use command
`screen -ls`

To attach to other screen, use command
`screen -r <session id>`